# How to delete Firefox Cookies and cache while program runs on Selenium Grid?

Tags: cookies, browser, selenium-grid

I am running Selenium Grid and most of my scripts fail due to inability to delete Firefox cookies.
Each testcase needs to delete browser cookies. If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `deleteCookie` function with Selenium to get rid of the cookies and you can put that in your Test Setup. The documentation for deleteCookie is below

> deleteCookie(name, optionsString)
>       Arguments:
>
> ```
>     * name - the name of the cookie to be deleted
>     * optionsString - options for the cookie. Currently supported
> ```
>
> options include 'path', 'domain' and
>   'recurse.' The optionsString's format
>   is "path=/path/, domain=.foo.com,
>   recurse=true". The order of options
>   are irrelevant. Note that specifying a
>   domain that isn't a subset of the
>   current domain will usually fail.
>
> ```
> Delete a named cookie with specified path and domain. Be careful;
> ```
>
> to delete a cookie, you need to delete
>   it using the exact same path and
>   domain that were used to create the
>   cookie. If the path is wrong, or the
>   domain is wrong, the cookie simply
>   won't be deleted. Also note that
>   specifying a domain that isn't a
>   subset of the current domain will
>   usually fail. Since there's no way to
>   discover at runtime the original path
>   and domain of a given cookie, we've
>   added an option called 'recurse' to
>   try all sub-domains of the current
>   domain with all paths that are a
>   subset of the current path. Beware;
>   this option can be slow. In big-O
>   notation, it operates in O(n*m) time,
>   where n is the number of dots in the
>   domain name and m is the number of
>   slashes in the path.